# Change content without changing client side URL

Tags: php, redirect

I want to show content of another page rather than the one user is viewing 
So basically the user would see

```
http://example.com/change.php
```

But the page will show the following address:

```
http://example.com/page.php?id=5&type=8
```

I've tried `include` but it seems that include cannot pass parameters. I need the URL to have the parameters & I can't change the `page.php` codes.

Comment: If you're using Apache, you can do this with `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I don't have access to Apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually can pass parameters, in this case GET parameters `id=5` and `type=8` can be passed to page.php like so:

```
$_GET['id'] = 5;
$_GET['type'] = 8;
include 'page.php';
```

Comment: Should I unset $_GET after include?

Comment: It depends on the logic of your change.php file, and page.php file. If page.php is affecting parameters in some way that breaks your code, or sets something that breaks what you use, you should do proper cleanup after including it. But if it does not, then no need.

Comment: It's not generally recommended to [modify superglobals](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76406/directly-modifying-superglobals), so this isn't the best solution but it does work.